# Using Viterbi algorithm to analyze sentences

Tags: clojure, machine-learning, natural-language-processing

I've probably done some pretty horrendous things here, but I'm throwing it out for people to give me some feedback that I can start using to immediately improve my Clojure coding style.

Additional suggestions would be performance enhancements as well as areas where I could use transients if it is advisable.

So far I've been told:

1. I should make use of `vector-of`
2. Use primitives such as int and double to avoid boxing and unboxing
3. Type hint string functions

I would be grateful for suggestions that I use to turn this code into more idiomatic Clojure code.

```
(ns tagger.core
  "Running Viterbi on some text"
  (:require [clojure.string :as str]
            [clojure.contrib.generic.functor :as functor]
            [clojure.contrib.math :as math]
            [clojure.set :as set]
            [clojure.data :as data]
            [clojure.data.finger-tree :as ft]))

(def ^:dynamic *epsilon* 0.01)

(defn applyAll [fs x]
  (map #(% x) fs))

(defn split-evenly [coll]
  (partition (quot (count coll) 10) coll))

(defn nil?-zero [fn & args]
  (let [val (apply fn args)]
    (if (nil? val)
      0
      val)))

;; Counts needed are:
;; word counts W
;; tag counts T
;; word-tag counts W-T
;; previous tag to current tag counts T(i+1)-Ti

;; Problem set
;; A sample set to play with
(def str-to-tags (slurp "resources/sample.txt"))

(defn str->tags [string]
  (filter #(not (empty? %))
          (str/split string #"[\s]")))

(defn tag->W-T [tag]
  "Converts a tag such as In/IN into a W-T such as [In IN]"
  (str/split tag #"[//]"))

(defn sentence->tags [sentence]
  (map #(second %) sentence))

(defn strip-tags [tag]
  (first tag))

(defn this-and-that [xs]
  (map-indexed (fn [i x]
                [x (concat (take i xs) 
                           (drop (inc i) xs))])
              xs))

(def cleaned-tag-str (filter #(= (count %) 2) (map tag->W-T (str->tags str-to-tags))))

(defn split-sentences [tag-str]
  "Splits the str into sentences"
  (reduce #(if (= (second (first %2)) ".")
             (ft/conjr (pop %1) (ft/conjr (peek %1) (first %2)))
             (ft/conjr %1 %2))
          (ft/double-list)
          (map #(apply ft/double-list %) (partition-by #(= "." (second %)) tag-str))))

(defn split-sentences-start-end [tag-str]
  "Splits the str into sentences with added start and end tags"
  (reduce #(if (= (second (first %2)) ".")
             (conj (vec (drop-last %1)) (conj (vec (conj (vec (conj (last %1) ["START" "START"]))
                                                         (first %2))) ["END" "END"]))
             (conj (vec %1) %2))
          []
          (partition-by #(= "." (second %)) tag-str)))

(def sentences (split-sentences cleaned-tag-str))

(def testing-and-training-sentences
  "A list containing 10 pairs of testing sentences and training sentences"
  (map (fn [[fst rst]] (ft/double-list fst (apply concat rst))) (this-and-that (split-evenly sentences))))

(defn add-start-end [sentence-list]
  (map #(ft/consl (ft/conjr % ["END" "END"]) ["START" "START"]) sentence-list))

(def testing-and-training-sentences-start-end (map #(map add-start-end %) testing-and-training-sentences))

(def training-tag-list-start-end (map (comp #(map sentence->tags %) second) testing-and-training-sentences-start-end))

(def testing-and-training-tag-list-start-end (map (fn [sample] (map #(map sentence->tags %) sample)) testing-and-training-sentences-start-end))

(defn insert [m k]
  "Inserts a key k into a map m if it does not exist or increments the count if it does"
  (let [val (m k)]
    (assoc m k (inc (if (nil? val) 0 val)))))

(defn nested-insert [m [word tag]]
  "Inserts a key k into a nested map m of tags and words if it does not exist or increments the count if it does"
  (let [val (get-in m [tag word])]
    (assoc-in m [tag word] (inc (if (nil? val) 0 val)))))

(defn word-count [tagged-str]
  "Example of how to get word counts"
  (reduce #(insert %1 (first %2)) {} tagged-str))

(defn tag-count [tagged-str]
  "Example of how to get tag counts"
  (reduce #(insert %1 (second %2)) {} tagged-str))

(defn nested-tag-word-count [tagged-str]
  "Nested counts in the format of {tag {word count}}"
  (reduce #(nested-insert %1 %2) {} tagged-str))

(def tag-count-training-list (map #(tag-count (apply concat (second %))) testing-and-training-sentences))

(def word-count-training-list (map #(word-count (apply concat (second %))) testing-and-training-sentences))

(def nested-tag-word-count-training-list (map #(nested-tag-word-count (apply concat (second %))) testing-and-training-sentences))

(defn out-of-step-list [tag-list]
  "Creates a list of vector pairs where the second element is the next values first element"
  (map vector (rest tag-list) tag-list))

(def training-previous-tag-tag-list-start-end (map #(map out-of-step-list %) training-tag-list-start-end))

(def training-tag-count-start-end (map (comp frequencies flatten) training-tag-list-start-end))

(defn nested-previous-tag-tag-count [previous-tag-tag-list]
   "Nested counts in the format of {prior-tag {tag count}}"
   (reduce #(nested-insert %1 %2) {} (apply concat previous-tag-tag-list)))

(def nested-previous-tag-tag-count-training-list (map nested-previous-tag-tag-count training-previous-tag-tag-list-start-end))

(defn unique-keys-count [m]
  (count (keys m)))

(def unique-words-count-training-list (map count word-count-training-list))

;; Calculating probabilities

(defn make-prob-fn-map
  [[nested-t-w-count word-count unique-wc nested-prior-t-t-count tag-count-st-end unique-tc]]
  {:prob-word-given-tag ;; Construct Emission Probabilities
   (fn [word tag]
     (let [word-given-tag (nil?-zero get-in nested-t-w-count [tag word])
           tc (nil?-zero word-count word)]
       (/ (+ word-given-tag *epsilon*)
          (+ tc (* *epsilon* unique-tc)))))
   :prob-tag-given-previous-tag ;; Construct Transition Probabilities
   (fn [tag previous-tag]
     (let [tag-given-prior-tag-prob (nil?-zero get-in nested-prior-t-t-count [previous-tag tag])
           tc (nil?-zero tag-count-st-end previous-tag)]
       (/ (+ tag-given-prior-tag-prob *epsilon*)
          (+ tc (* *epsilon* unique-tc)))))})

(defn viterbi-init [v path obs states start-p emit-p]
  "Initializes viterbi for us"
  (reduce
   #(into %1 {%2 [(* (start-p %2)
                     (emit-p (first obs) %2))
                  (conj path %2)]})
   {}
   states))

(defn extract-prob-state [v path]
  "Extracts the current probability and state for a given [v path]"
  [(first (v path)) path])

(defn viterbi-step [prior obs states trans-p emit-p]
  "Goes through one step of viterbi for us, taking a prior state and performing one step"
  (apply merge (map
                (comp (fn [[path v]] {(last path) [v path]}) #(apply max-key val %) #(apply merge %))
                ((fn [obs]
                   (map #(applyAll (map (comp (fn [[v past-st]]
                                                (fn [current-st]
                                                  {(conj (second (prior past-st)) current-st)
                                                   (* v (trans-p current-st past-st)
                                                      (emit-p obs current-st))}))
                                              (partial extract-prob-state prior)) states) %) states))
                 obs))))

(defn viterbi [observations states start-prob trans-prob emit-prob]
  (let [init (viterbi-init [] [] observations states start-prob emit-prob)]
        (reduce #(viterbi-step %1 %2 states trans-prob emit-prob) init (rest observations))))

(defn viterbi-solution [observations states start-prob trans-prob emit-prob]
  (apply max-key #(first (val %)) (viterbi observations states start-prob trans-prob emit-prob)))

(defn extract-path [solution]
  "Extracts the path from a viterbi solution"
  (second (second solution)))

(defn extract-tag-count [seq]
  (reduce insert {} (flatten (map second (second seq)))))

(defn extract-states [seq]
  (into #{} (flatten (map #(map second %) (second seq)))))

(defn extract-observations [seq]
  (map #(map first %) (first seq)))

(defn extract-testing-tags [seq]
  (map #(map second %) (first seq)))

(defn compare-matches [compare]
  "Compares vector containing a path and testing set and gives the matches"
  (map (comp (fn [m] (/ (nil?-zero m true) (+ (nil?-zero m true) (nil?-zero m false)))) frequencies (fn [[a b]] (map #(= %1 %2) a b))) compare))

(defn average-accuracy [accuracy-scores]
  (/ (apply + accuracy-scores) (double (count accuracy-scores))))

(defn run-viterbi []
  "Runs viterbi with transition and emission calculated using the same training data via cross validation"
  (let [states (map extract-states testing-and-training-sentences)
        observations (map extract-observations testing-and-training-sentences)
        prob-map (map make-prob-fn-map (map vector nested-tag-word-count-training-list word-count-training-list unique-words-count-training-list nested-previous-tag-tag-count-training-list training-tag-count-start-end (map count states)))
        transition-prob (map :prob-tag-given-previous-tag prob-map)
        emission-prob (map :prob-word-given-tag prob-map)
        start-prob (map (fn [trans-p] #(trans-p % "START")) transition-prob)
        testing-tags-list (map extract-testing-tags testing-and-training-sentences)]
    (map #(map vector %1 %2)
         testing-tags-list
         (map (fn [[obs-list sts start-p trans-p emit-p]]
                (map (fn [obs]
                       (extract-path (viterbi-solution obs sts start-p trans-p emit-p))) obs-list))
              (map vector observations states start-prob transition-prob emission-prob)))))

(defn -main []
  (average-accuracy (map (comp average-accuracy compare-matches) (run-viterbi))))

;; Checking functions

(defn close-to-1 [val]
  (> 0.000001 (math/abs (- 1 val))))

;; Assert that Probabilities are sensible?

(defn check-probs? []
  (assert
   (let [states (map extract-states testing-and-training-sentences)
         observations (map extract-observations testing-and-training-sentences)
         prob-map (map make-prob-fn-map (map vector nested-tag-word-count-training-list word-count-training-list unique-words-count-training-list nested-previous-tag-tag-count-training-list training-tag-count-start-end (map count states)))
         transition-prob (map :prob-tag-given-previous-tag prob-map)
         emission-prob (map :prob-word-given-tag prob-map)
         start-prob (map (fn [trans-p] #(trans-p % "START")) transition-prob)
         testing-tags-list (map extract-testing-tags testing-and-training-sentences)]
     (every? true? (map close-to-1 (map (fn [[start-pr st]] (apply + (map start-pr st))) (map vector start-prob states)))))
   "Start Probabilities are not sensible")
  (assert
   (let [states (map extract-states testing-and-training-sentences)
         observations (map extract-observations testing-and-training-sentences)
         prob-map (map make-prob-fn-map (map vector nested-tag-word-count-training-list word-count-training-list unique-words-count-training-list nested-previous-tag-tag-count-training-list training-tag-count-start-end (map count states)))
         transition-prob (map :prob-tag-given-previous-tag prob-map)
         emission-prob (map :prob-word-given-tag prob-map)
         start-prob (map #(partial % "START") transition-prob)
         testing-tags-list (map extract-testing-tags testing-and-training-sentences)]
     (every? true? (map (fn [[emit-pr st wctl]] (every? true? (map close-to-1 (map (fn [word] (apply + (map #(emit-pr word %) st))) (keys wctl))))) (map vector emission-prob states word-count-training-list))))
   "Emmission probabilities are not sensible")
  (assert
   (every? true? (let [states (map extract-states testing-and-training-sentences)
                       observations (map extract-observations testing-and-training-sentences)
                       prob-map (map make-prob-fn-map (map vector nested-tag-word-count-training-list word-count-training-list unique-words-count-training-list nested-previous-tag-tag-count-training-list training-tag-count-start-end (map count states)))
                       transition-prob (map :prob-tag-given-previous-tag prob-map)
                       emission-prob (map :prob-word-given-tag prob-map)
                       start-prob (map #(partial % "START") transition-prob)
                       testing-tags-list (map extract-testing-tags testing-and-training-sentences)]
                   (map (fn [[trans-pr st]] (every? true? (map close-to-1 (map (fn [prior] (apply + (map #(trans-pr % prior) st))) (disj st "."))))) (map vector transition-prob states))))
   "Transisition probabilities are not sensible"))
```

Here is sample.txt:

> ```
> ======================================
>
> In/IN 
> [ an/DT Oct./NNP 19/CD review/NN ]
> of/IN ``/`` 
> [ The/DT Misanthrope/NN ]
> ''/'' at/IN 
> [ Chicago/NNP 's/POS Goodman/NNP Theatre/NNP ]
>  (/( 
> [ ``/`` Revitalized/VBN Classics/NNS ]
> Take/VBP 
> [ the/DT Stage/NN ]
> in/IN 
> [ Windy/NNP City/NNP ]
> ,/, ''/'' 
> [ Leisure/NN ]
> &/CC 
> [ Arts/NNS ]
>  )/) ,/, 
> [ the/DT role/NN ]
> of/IN 
> [ Celimene/NNP ]
> ,/, played/VBN by/IN 
> [ Kim/NNP Cattrall/NNP ]
> ,/, was/VBD mistakenly/RB attributed/VBN to/TO 
> [ Christina/NNP Haag/NNP ]
> ./. 
>
> [ Ms./NNP Haag/NNP ]
> plays/VBZ 
> [ Elianti/NNP ]
> ./. 
>
> ======================================
>
>  (/( See/VB :/: ``/`` 
> [ Revitalized/VBN Classics/NNS ]
> Take/VBP 
> [ the/DT Stage/NN ]
> in/IN 
> [ Windy/NNP City/NNP ]
> ''/'' --/: 
> [ WSJ/NNP Oct./NNP 19/CD ]
> ,/, 
> [ 1989/CD ]
>
> )/) 
> ======================================
>
>
>
>
> ======================================
>
> [ Rolls-Royce/NNP Motor/NNP Cars/NNPS Inc./NNP ]
> said/VBD 
> [ it/PRP ]
> expects/VBZ 
> [ its/PRP$ U.S./NNP sales/NNS ]
> to/TO remain/VB 
> [ steady/JJ ]
> at/IN about/IN 
> [ 1,200/CD cars/NNS ]
> in/IN 
> [ 1990/CD ]
> ./. 
>
> [ The/DT luxury/NN auto/NN maker/NN last/JJ year/NN ]
> sold/VBD 
> [ 1,214/CD cars/NNS ]
> in/IN 
> [ the/DT U.S./NNP Howard/NNP Mosher/NNP ]
> ,/, 
> [ president/NN ]
> and/CC 
> [ chief/JJ executive/NN officer/NN ]
> ,/, said/VBD 
> [ he/PRP ]
> anticipates/VBZ 
> [ growth/NN ]
> for/IN 
> [ the/DT luxury/NN auto/NN maker/NN ]
> in/IN 
> [ Britain/NNP ]
> and/CC 
> [ Europe/NNP ]
> ,/, and/CC in/IN 
> [ Far/JJ Eastern/JJ markets/NNS ]
> ./. 
>
>
>
> ======================================
>
> [ BELL/NNP INDUSTRIES/NNP Inc./NNP ]
> increased/VBD 
> [ its/PRP$ quarterly/NN ]
> to/TO 
> [ 10/CD cents/NNS ]
> from/IN 
> [ seven/CD cents/NNS ]
>
> [ a/DT share/NN ]
> ./. 
>
> [ The/DT new/JJ rate/NN ]
> will/MD be/VB 
> [ payable/JJ Feb./NNP 15/CD ]
> ./. 
>
> [ A/DT record/NN date/NN has/VBZ n't/RB ]
> been/VBN set/VBN ./. 
>
> [ Bell/NNP ]
> ,/, based/VBN in/IN 
> [ Los/NNP Angeles/NNP ]
> ,/, makes/VBZ and/CC distributes/VBZ 
> [ electronic/JJ ]
> ,/, 
> [ computer/NN ]
> and/CC 
> [ building/NN products/NNS ]
> ./. 
>
>
>
> ======================================
>
> [ Investors/NNS ]
> are/VBP appealing/VBG to/TO 
> [ the/DT Securities/NNPS ]
> and/CC 
> [ Exchange/NNP Commission/NNP ]
> not/RB to/TO limit/VB 
> [ their/PRP$ access/NN ]
> to/TO 
> [ information/NN ]
> about/IN 
> [ stock/NN purchases/NNS ]
> and/CC 
> [ sales/NNS ]
> by/IN 
> [ corporate/JJ insiders/NNS ]
> ./. 
>
> ======================================
>
> [ A/DT SEC/NNP proposal/NN ]
> to/TO ease/VB reporting/NN 
> [ requirements/NNS ]
> for/IN 
> [ some/DT company/NN executives/NNS ]
> would/MD undermine/VB 
> [ the/DT usefulness/NN ]
> of/IN 
> [ information/NN ]
> on/IN 
> [ insider/NN trades/NNS ]
> as/IN 
> [ a/DT stock-picking/JJ tool/NN ]
> ,/, 
> [ individual/JJ investors/NNS ]
> and/CC 
> [ professional/JJ money/NN managers/NNS ]
> contend/VBP ./.
> ```

Comment: This is not "Viterbi", but "applying Viterbi to part-of-speech tagging". The Viterbi is very useful in other areas, not only NLP. I would have liked to comment on the actual algorithm, but you don't have enough comments here. Oh, and since you're have nice pure function, you could test them, eg. `(deftest test-split (is (= ["a" b"] "a b")))` or something like this.

Comment: Hi @Cygal, what do you mean that I don't "have enough comments here". Good point, I'll add the test cases :)...

Comment: Oops, the comments are in docstrings. I guess it takes just too much effort to comment on the algorithm, and I can't comment on the Clojure since, well, I don't know Clojure. :)

Comment: Nobody in for a Clojure review?

Comment: Looks like it doesn't it :(, thanks for putting up the bounty though @Cygal!

Answer (score 6):

First of all, good job! This is obviously a complex algorithm and it looks like it's working.

I'm going to do this incrementally. So I'll save this and keep editing as I go. And since it's so long, I won't get to everything. Plus I don't understand the algorithm too well.

First of all, doc strings in Clojure go before the arguments. I used to make this mistake all the time. The reason is that you can have multi-variate functions.

1:

```
(defn insert [m k]
  "Inserts a key k into a map m if it does not exist or increments the count if it does"
  (let [val (m k)]
    (assoc m k (inc (if (nil? val) 0 val)))))
```

My version:

```
(defn insert 
  "Inserts a key k into a map m if it does not exist or increments the count if it does"
  [m k]
  (update-in m [k] (fnil inc 0)))
```

See [update-in](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/update-in) and [fnil](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/fnil).

2:

`#()` construction is unnecessary here:

```
(defn sentence->tags [sentence]
  (map #(second %) sentence))
```

My version:

```
(defn sentence->tags [sentence]
  (map second sentence))
```

3:

```
(defn word-count [tagged-str]
  "Example of how to get word counts"
  (reduce #(insert %1 (first %2)) {} tagged-str))
```

Could this be replaced by using [frequencies](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/frequencies)?

4:

Now it's starting to get hairy. I may make some mistakes here, because the code is not factored.

```
(defn viterbi-init [v path obs states start-p emit-p]
  "Initializes viterbi for us"
  (reduce
    #(into %1 {%2 [(* (start-p %2)
                 (emit-p (first obs) %2))
              (conj path %2)]})
    {}
    states))
```

This definitely has too many levels of into/reduce. You could do a `(reduce #(assoc %1 %s ...) {} states)` pattern. Do we need `v`? And why are we passing in a list `obs` when we only need the first? And it's often a good idea to put the driving sequence in the first or last position, so you can do threading. Let's try it this way:

```
(defn viterbi-init 
  "Initializes viterbi for us"
  [states path ob start-p emit-p]
  (into {}
    (for [state states]
      [state
       [(* (start-p state) (emit-p ob state))
        (conj path state)]])))
```

5:

This one is very hairy. I don't quite understand it, but I will try.

```
(defn viterbi-step [prior obs states trans-p emit-p]
  "Goes through one step of viterbi for us, taking a prior state and performing one step"
  (apply merge (map
                (comp (fn [[path v]] {(last path) [v path]}) #(apply max-key val %) #(apply merge %))
                ((fn [obs]
                   (map #(applyAll (map (comp (fn [[v past-st]]
                                                (fn [current-st]
                                                  {(conj (second (prior past-st)) current-st)
                                                   (* v (trans-p current-st past-st)
                                                      (emit-p obs current-st))}))
                                              (partial extract-prob-state prior)) states) %) states))
                 obs))))
```

So, I tried and failed to refactor this myself. But I will give my general feedback. What this function, which is a map of a map of a map of a map, tells me is that there is a failure of abstraction. `viterbi-step` should be should be a high-level function which should read somewhat like the inner loop of a pseudo-code implementation of Viterbi. This function relies too much on the structure of the data structures involved. Deeply nested structures are common, but a single function that accesses them so deeply is not. A good rule of thumb is at most 1 nested map/reduce within a function.

There need to be functions which act as your primitive operations here. I can see that you began writing some near the top. You should continue that trend here. Then your functions would be operating at a certain level and calling functions from the level below.

An alternative approach would be to turn the algorithm into a sequential series of steps. This may or may not apply here, but it is hard for me to tell. As an example (not real code!):

```
(defn viterbi-step [prior obs states trans-p emit-p]
  (-> obs
    (calculate-priors)
    (extract-prob-states states)
    (extract-path)
    (merge)))
```

Again, it's just an example. But the idea is that each function takes the data it needs and creates a new data structure that is the result of that calculation. I don't know if this is possible with this algorithm. But it could be. One hint I can give is that you know you are on the right track when your functions are returning "appropriate" data structures. That is, when the data is a mapping, you return a map. When it's a set, you return a set. Also, the functions don't take much more data than they need to calculate the answer. I suggest you take the iterative algorithm description and work backwards from the final output.

Again, nice going. It was a pleasure to go through it.

Comment: Hi @Eric, thanks for the feedback, I'm a bit busy right now (as it's been a while since I coded this, but I'll have a bash later, likely next weekend at going through the code in my question, cleaning it up and incorporating your suggestions.)

Answer (score 5):

Another suggestion would be to use maps as method arguments.

instead of :

```
(defn viterbi-step [prior obs states trans-p emit-p]
```

using maps:

```
(defn viterbi-step [{:keys [prior obs states trans-p emit-p] :as m}]
```

So when viterbi-step is called, you can avoid passing all the arguments, instead you can *assoc* the new arguments onto the map passed to the existing method:

```
(defn viterbi [observations states start-prob trans-prob emit-prob]
  (let [init (viterbi-init [] [] observations states start-prob emit-prob)]
        (reduce #(viterbi-step (assoc m :prior %1 :obs %2))  init (rest observations))))
```

We can avoid having to type out all the arguments again just to pass it to another function. Rewriting the viterbi-solution method thus:

```
(defn viterbi-solution [{:keys [observations states start-prob trans-prob emit-prob] :as m}]
  (apply max-key #(first (val %)) (viterbi m)))
```